# Flot chart is there possibility to add additional legend

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I have a bar chart which displays a legend. Can I add another legend with my own data? I want to add it somewhere on the chart, for example where the arrow on the image is pointing.[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text) and come back if you have concrete problems or questions.

Answer (score 0):

Is your requirement that there be two legends?  If you want to style the one that is already there, you could retrieve the legend using jquery or style is using css by using

```
.legend {

}
```

in css or

```
$('.legend')
```

in jquery.  Note that if you want to go this route, you could then [use the position option for the legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951012/flot-pie-chart-change-position-of-legends) to place it on the plot.

If you need a second legend, maybe retrieving using the jquery above and using [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) might be the way to go.